# Problema con una lista y un ciclo y un if - Python?

Tags: python, archivo, bucles

Tengo un ejercicio que es medio largo de explicar. Así que voy a intentar ser lo más claro posible.

Tengo 3 archivos de texto
Los archivos de texto son:

Cursadas.csv: Almacena un código de materia, el número identificatorio de un alumno y la nota que se saco en la matería.

```
137,152001,4.0
127,151988,6.0
137,151988,7.5
132,152002,2.0
132,151988,6.0
127,152001,2.0
127,180372,10.0
```

Alumnos.csv, que contiene nuevamente el numero identificatorio del alumno y el nombre y apellido del alumno

```
152002,Juan Gonzalez
152001,Ana Martinez
151988,Ricardo Bochini
180372,Vicente Pernia
```

materias.csv, que contiene nuevamente el código de la matería y el nombre de la materia.

```
132,Informatica Gral
127,Algebra y Geometria
137,Fisica I
```

Lo que tengo que hacer en el ejercicio es cargar cada uno de los archivos a una lista. Luego, pedir el nombre de un alumno y tengo que imprimir una nueva lista en donde contenga el codigo de las materias aprobadas por dicho alumno (Se aprueba con 4) y la nota.
Lo estoy haciendo y practicamente lo tengo hecho. El problema es que en la función "aprobadas" hay un IF en donde esta entrando todo y me guarda siempre las notas mayores a 4 pero de cualquier alumno y no del que estoy pidiendo.
Adjunto el código porque quizas es algo facil que se me esta pasando pero no lo encuentro.

```
from io import open

def cargaalumnos(lstalumnos,ori):
    
    registro=0
    pal=""
    archivo=open(ori,"r")
    for linea in archivo.readlines():
        linea=linea.split(",")
        registro=int(linea[0])
        pal=str(linea[1][:-1])
        lstalumnos.append([registro,pal])
    archivo.close()

def cargamaterias(lstmaterias,ori):
    registro=0
    pal=""
    archivo=open(ori,"r")
    for linea in archivo.readlines():
        linea=linea.split(",")
        registro=int(linea[0])
        pal=linea[1][:-1]
        lstmaterias.append([registro,pal])
    archivo.close()

def cargarcursadas(lstcursadas,ori):
    archivo=open(ori,"r")
    codigo=0
    registro=0
    nota=0
    for linea in archivo.readlines():
        linea=linea.split(",")
        codigo=int(linea[0])
        registro=int(linea[1])
        nota=float(linea[2])
        lstcursadas.append([codigo,registro,nota])
    archivo.close()

def aprobadas(lstalumnos,lstmaterias,lstcursadas,alumno):
    i=0
    j=0
    aux=[]
    while(i<len(lstalumnos)):
        while(j<len(lstcursadas)):
            if(lstcursadas[j][1]==lstalumnos[i][0]):
                if(lstcursadas[j][2]>=4):
                    aux.append([lstcursadas[j][0],lstcursadas[j][2]])
            j=j+1
        j=0
        i=i+1
    print(aux)


def main():
    lstalumnos=[]
    lstmaterias=[]
    lstcursadas=[]
    cargaalumnos(lstalumnos,"alumnos.csv")
    cargamaterias(lstmaterias,"materias.csv")
    cargarcursadas(lstcursadas,"cursadas.csv")
    alumno=input("Ingrese nombre del alumno:")
    aprobadas(lstalumnos,lstmaterias,lstcursadas,alumno)
    
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
def main():
    alumno=input("alumno: ")
    promedio=4
    a = cargarArchivo("a.txt")
    m = cargarArchivo("m.txt")
    c = cargarArchivo("c.txt")
    data = sustituir(m,c,a)
    u = buscar(alumno,promedio,data)

    # validamos
    if u:
        for x in u:
            print(f"{x[1]} aprovo la materia {x[0]} con promedio de {x[2]}")
    else:
        print(f"sin resultados para el alumno {alumno}")


# cambia los ids por nombre de materia y alumno
def sustituir(materias,cursados,alumnos):
    # recorre los cursados
    # enumerate() enumera los items de un arreglo
    # para poder usar indices y valor
    for k,v in enumerate(cursados):
        # recorremos las materias
        for n in materias:
            # si el id de la materia coincide con el curso
            if n[0] == v[0]:
                # remplazamos el numero por el nombre de la materia
                # tambien se prodia hacer un cursados[k][0].append(n[1]) si no se desea remplazar
                cursados[k][0] = n[1]
        # recorremos los alumnos
        for a in alumnos:
            # si el id del alumno coincide con el id de cursados
            if a[0] == v[1]:
                # remplazamos el numero por el nombre del alumno
                # tambien se prodia hacer un cursados[k][1].append(a[1]) si no se desea remplazar
                cursados[k][1] = a[1]

    # regresamo el numero arreglo
    return cursados

def buscar(name,promedio,data):
    # guardaras las materia aprovadas
    aprovadas = []
    # si no se envia nombre
    if not name:
        return "debes introducir un nombre a buscar"

    # recorremos la data
    for x in data:
        # eliminamos los espacios de los nombre y pasamos a mayuscula
        # pasamos el promedio a flotante y validamos que sea mayor o igual al promedio requerido
        # para busquedas exactas podemos remplazar "in" por "==" 
        if name.upper().strip() in x[1].upper().strip() and float(x[2]) >= promedio:
            # añadimos a aprovadas nombre la materia y nota
            aprovadas.append(x)
    # retornamos los aprovados
    return aprovadas


# cargamos los archivos
def cargarArchivo(file):
        # guardara el archivo
        fd=[]
        # abrimos el archivo
        with open(file,"r") as f:
            # recorremos las lineas
            for line in f.readlines():
                # creamos un arreglo separado por comas
                # añadimos al arreglo fd
                fd.append(line.strip().split(","))
        # retornamos el contenido del archivo
        return fd


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```